# How can I create an array of objects in Kotlin without initialization and a specific number of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, object, kotlin

I want to create an Array of objects with a specific number of elements in Kotlin, the problem is I don't now the current values for initialization of every object in the declaration, I tried:

```
var miArreglo = Array<Medico>(20, {null})
```

in Java, I have this and is exactly what I want, but i need it in Kotlin. :

```
Medico[] medicos = new Medico[20];

for(int i = 0 ; i < medicos.length; i++){
    medicos[i] = new Medico();

}
```

What would be the Kotlink equivalent of the above Java code?

Also, I tried with:

```
var misDoctores = arrayOfNulls<medic>(20)

for(i in misDoctores ){
    i = medic()
}
```

But I Android Studio show me the message: "Val cannot be reassigned"

Comment: If you don't know the current values, you are better off using a List instead, then you can just add the values as you go along. Also, you can find out the size of the list. In your case, the problem was i is declared as val, so you can't re-assign.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The Kotlin equivalent of that could would be this:

```
val miArreglo = Array(20) { Medico() }
```

But I would strongly advice you to using [Lists](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html) in Kotlin because they are way more flexible. In your case the `List` would not need to be mutable and thus I would advice something like this:

```
val miArreglo = List(20) { Medico() }
```

The two snippets above can be easily explained. The first parameter is *obviously* the `Array` or `List` size as in Java and the second is a lambda function, which is the `init { ... }` function. The `init { ... }` function can consist of some kind of operation and the last value will always be the return type and the returned value, i.e. in this case a `Medico` object.

I also chose to use a `val` instead of a `var` because `List`'s and `Array`'s should not be reassigned. If you want to edit your `List`, please use a `MutableList` instead.

```
val miArreglo = MutableList(20) { Medico() }
```

You can edit this list then, e.g.:

```
miArreglo.add(Medico())
```

Comment: You can also pass id parameter: List(20) { id -> Medico() }

Comment: how to use list in kotlin without size given? here its given as 20.

Answer (score 4):

If you want list of nullable objects, we can do something like this

```
val fragment : Array<Fragment?> = Array(4) { null }
```

Comment: This is the equivalent to the question since in Java, an array can contain a null value.